# .exe running as scheduled task doesn't write to file

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I have a Windows XP application complied with MinGW that collects information about the open processes, windows, threads, etc.  It also creates a scheduled task of itself to run once a minute.  I have two functions that open a text file, write to it, and close it.  The second function works perfectly, the first only works on the initial run.  If I run it via executing the .exe manually, it's fine.  If it runs as a scheduled task, it won't write.  I open both files in functions with

`ofstream myfile;`

`myfile.open(filepath, ios::app)`

Write to them using

`myfile << "Things to write" << somevar << endl;`

And close them with `myfile.close()`

For some reason, when running as a scheduled task, the first does not write to the file.  I tried commenting out everything but that function and the scheduled task code, and the result was the same.  Worked the first time, but not on subsequent runs.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)  \\This only works when run manually, broken as schtask
{
    char class_name[80];
    char title[80];
    const char* filepath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Microsoft\\Protect\\taskinfo.txt";
    ofstream myfile;

    if (IsAltTabWindow(hwnd))
    {
        myfile.open (filepath, ios::app);
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {          
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        GetClassName(hwnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
        GetWindowText(hwnd,title, sizeof(title));
        MessageBox(NULL, title, NULL, MB_OK);  \\Pop up for debugging purposes.  
        myfile << "Window title: " << title << "        ";
        myfile << "PID: " << pid << endl;
        }
        else
           MessageBox(NULL, "ERROR", NULL, MB_OK);
        myfile.close();
    }          
}

int GetThreads() \\This works properly.  Run manually or as schtask, it opens and writes to the file properly
{
   const char* filepath = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Microsoft\\Protect\\taskinfo.txt";
   ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open (filepath, ios::app);
   HANDLE h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
   if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
    THREADENTRY32 te;
    te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
    if (Thread32First(h, &te))
  {
     do
   {
       if (te.dwSize >= FIELD_OFFSET(THREADENTRY32, th32OwnerProcessID) +
                      sizeof(te.th32OwnerProcessID))
     {
         myfile << "PID: " << te.th32OwnerProcessID << endl;
         myfile << "Thread: " << te.th32ThreadID << endl;                          
     }
     te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
   }   while (Thread32Next(h, &te));
  }
    CloseHandle(h);
}
   myfile.close();
   return 0;
}


//Here's how they're called
int main()
{
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, sizeof(szPath));
    string s2 = "schtasks /Create /RU system /SC MINUTE /TN \"schtask\" /TR \"\\\"";
    string s3 = s2+szPath+"\"\"";
    const char * c =s3.c_str();
    system("schtasks /delete /TN \"schtask\" /F");
    system(c);
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
    GetThreads();
    return 0;
}
```

I've scanned it and run a debugger with generous breakpoints but I can't find where the point of failure it.  As far as I've been able to find in my troubleshooting, the error occurs specifically in the writing.  There's data to write and it opens the file properly, just like the second, working function.

EDIT: After several hours of debugging, I've found that `EnumWindowsProc` never executes after the first run.  I tried opening and writing a test message at the top of the process before anything else and it doesn't go through the second time.

Comment: May be s.th. about account rights used when it's running as scheduled task? Under which account does it run as scheduled task?

Comment: It runs under system, made possible by making sure the first run is on an admin account.

Comment: I'd follow @Lochemage's suggestion and try to write into some different folder, needing less access rights.

Comment: This should never work, unless you've totally disabled UAC on your system. Nothing should be able to write to the `Windows` folder (or anything beneath it) without administrative access; even if you're running as an admin, you should be prompted to confirm you really want to write there. You need to write to a proper location (somewhere in `C:\Users`, preferably a location for the currently logged in user obtained by the proper WinAPI call). Allowing anything to write willy-nilly to the protected system folders is like inviting malware to set up housekeeping; it's simply foolish nowdays.

Comment: As mentioned, this is a Win XP application.  On the admin account I can make all the .txt files I want in `WINDOWS`.  Lochemage suggested the same thing you did and I still got the same result.  `EnumWindowsProc()` only wrote out on the first run, while `GetThreads()` writes out every time.  I added a `MessageBox()` to `EnumWindowsProc()` for debugging purposes and it doesn't show on subsequent runs, though I believe this is due to the nature of the scheduled task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I was creating the schtask under "SYSTEM", and "SYSTEM" has no desktop to be enumerated.  I changed it to run under the current user and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider changing the folder where your text file lives, WINDOWS folder is a very protected area and changes to files that already exist there can only be made under elevated status (admin permission).  My guess is that your scheduled task isn't elevated like it should be for altering files in that folder.

Comment: Then why does the second function work?  If they both failed to write then that might be the case, but one works and the other doesn't.  Previous versions of the program piped system call outputs to a text file in the WINDOWS folder on XP.

Comment: I changed to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents.  Same result